# meaning of ちゃった verb ending

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language

I've seen many verbs that end with ちゃった and would like to know what that means.

For example: リボンも切れ**ちゃった**。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

〜ちゃった is an informal contraction of 〜てしまった, usually expressing regret or disappointment.  So your example is the same as

> - リボンも切れてしまいました

---

See also

- [Verb in ている form ends with しまう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26020/78)
- [「しまう」 as an auxiliary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21026/78)

Comment: Thanks. The sentence totally makes sense to me now. Especially since I realized I misspelled a word.. it should have been 干切れちゃった.